# Play Framework macro inception and joda datetime to json

Tags: json, scala, datetime, playframework

I would like to use macro inception to convert my case classes to json.

```
case class User(name: String, created: DateTime)
...
implicit val UserWrites = Json.writes[User]
```

However in this case if I set up custom DateTime write like this:

```
implicit val myJodaDateWrites = Writes.jodaDateWrites("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Serializer still uses default joda DateTime converter. I do not want to set it explicitly like this:

```
  val userWrites: Writes[User] = (
      (JsPath \ "name").write[String] and
      (JsPath \ "created").write[DateTime](myJodaDateWrites)
  )(unlift(User.unapply))
```

I would rather have it done implicitly. Is it possible?

UPDATE:

I found out User write didn't see my custom DateTime writer, because it was declared before I declared custom writer. Changing the order fixed the problem.

Comment: Are you sure your myJodaDateWrites is visible in scope of userWrites?

Comment: @Tyth Both are members of companion object `object User`

Comment: Oh... You were right...